# Just the minus sign in the exponent

Tags: symbols

If cells present or do not present a certain protein (e.g. CD133) it is a common way to write CD133+ or CD44-, but the +/- signs belong to the exponent. 
I have tried the following codes to get the minus displayed:

1. `CD133\texsuperscript{-}`
2. `CD133\textsuperscript{$-$}`
3. `$CD133^{-}$`

But all these tries ended up in the pdf document only as CD133 without the exponent. Interestingly, with the + there are no problemsCD133\texsuperscript{+}.
How can I achieve to display only the - as exponent for CD133?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please tell us (a) *how* you compile the document to produce a pdf file and (b) which pdf viewer you employ.

Comment: all three of the forms that you show should make a dash in the output, the first one is a subscripted hyphen not a subscripted minus so will be very small. Usually, for chemistry I think it is recommended to use one of the specialist packages for setting chemical formulae rather than using `\textsuperscript` etc but still, it should work.

Comment: I know found the mistake. Somehow the minus sign did change because I copied it from word. I replaced the wrong minus sign with the $-$ and it works fine (after I updated). How can I make sure that I use the right minus sign outside of the math environment?

Answer (score 2):

`CD133$^{-}$`, `CD133\textsuperscript{$-$}`, and `CD133\textsuperscript{\textminus}` -- where `\textminus` is a macro defined by the `textcomp` package -- should all give the desired result, as long as you use pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or XeLaTeX to compile the document to pdf.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for '\textminus' macro
\begin{document}
CD133$^{-}$ 

CD133\textsuperscript{$-$}

CD133\textsuperscript{\textminus}
\end{document}
```

Comment: CD133\textsuperscript{$-$} this is how I would be happy with the result. Unfortunately, I cannot really tell you which pdf compile I use. I just started to work with aquamacs Emacs and this is my LaTex experience. How do I see which compiler is used?

Comment: @Tyemo - Emacs is a front-end to a TeX distribution. Can you locate the main log file (`\jobname.log`)? Its first line should tell you which TeX program is in use. E.g., something like "This is pdfTeX, Version ...".

Comment: This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)  (format=lualatex 2016.8.31)  25 JUN 2018 23:13. I cannot change to LuaLaTex or pdfLaTex. Do you know how to do it? I'm sorry that I bother you with such simple problems

Comment: @Tyemo - Which TeX engine you use is determined by the front-end software -- aquamacs/emacs, right? Can you locate a user guide for aquamacs? By the way, updating your TeX distribution from TeXLive2016 to TeXLive2018 might be a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

In a similar case, with pdfLaTeX and custom fonts I used something along

- `CD27\textsuperscript{+}`
- `CD271\textsuperscript{$-$} %% might be not best`

Actually, I used `pandoc` and its `CD34^+^` syntax.

I also updated the protrusion for the + and - to reach into the page border with `microtype` package:

```
%%%%% fix protrusion on right margin for superscript
%%%%% http://www.khirevich.com/latex/microtype/

\SetProtrusion{encoding={*},family={zgmx},series={*},size={6,7,8,footnotesize,small,scriptsize}}
              {+={ ,400},-={ ,550}, %% this is the wrong -, notice we use
                                    %% math one in CD34- and like above
              %% from khirevich, lessened a bit
              1={ ,750},2={ ,500},3={ ,500},4={ ,500},5={ ,500},
              6={ ,500},7={ ,600},8={ ,500},9={ ,500},0={ ,500}}
\SetProtrusion{encoding={*},family={zsups},series={*},size={*}} %% let's get dangerous!
              {+={ ,400},-={ ,550}, %% this is the wrong -, see above
              %% from khirevich, lessened a bit
              1={ ,750},2={ ,500},3={ ,500},4={ ,500},5={ ,500},
              6={ ,500},7={ ,600},8={ ,500},9={ ,500},0={ ,500}}
```